# How to split a html table by columns for responsive design

Tags: html, css, media-queries

We've checked the web and SO for a solution to this, but have found nothing to solve our specific problem.

We are using the following table format for a contact formular:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">COL1-2</td>
    <td colspan="2">COL3-4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>COL1</td>
    <td>COL2</td>
    <td>COL3</td>
    <td>COL4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>COL1</td>
    <td>COL2</td>
    <td>COL3</td>
    <td>COL4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>COL1</td>
    <td>COL2</td>
    <td>COL3</td>
    <td>COL4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using media queries, is it possible to make COLS3 & 4 sit under COLS1 &2 (see below)?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">COL1-2</td>
    <tr>
      <td>COL1</td>
      <td>COL2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>COL1</td>
      <td>COL2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>COL1</td>
      <td>COL2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">COL3-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>COL3</td>
      <td>COL4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>COL3</td>
      <td>COL4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>COL3</td>
      <td>COL4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes but not purely in CSS alone.  You could restructure the table so that column 1 and 2 are nested within a table, and column 3 and 4 are nested within a table.  If you restuctured the table as such, you could create a media query to assign each of the two tables display block, so the table to the right would wrap under the table on the left.

```css
table table { display:inline-block;vertical-align:top; }
```

```html
<table border="1">
      <tr>
          <td class="wrap">
              <table border="1">
                  <tr><td colspan="2">COL1-2</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>COL1</td><td>COL2</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>COL1</td><td>COL2</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>COL1</td><td>COL2</td></tr>
              </table>
              <table border="1">
                  <tr><td colspan="2">COL3-4</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>COL3</td><td>COL4</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>COL3</td><td>COL4</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>COL3</td><td>COL4</td></tr>
              </table>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

`table table { display: block; }` to wrap.

Comment: Note: This will ruin a lot of the native table functionality. E.g., the heights of the cells in different columns won't necessarily match up into neat rows. And the widths won't adjust when there isn't enough room - columns will just break off to display underneath the others.