# Is it possible to split css table into multiple columns?

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive table, but I have no idea about how can I achieve this. After googling, could not find a solution.

So, I have this table in desktop view:

```
    1   2   3   

I   B   C   D

II  C   D   E

III D   E   F

IV  E   F   G
```

And I'm trying to get this in responsive view:

```
   1
I     B
II    C
III   D
IV    E

   2
I     C
II    D
III   E
IV    F

etc..
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a html table by columns for responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009984/how-to-split-a-html-table-by-columns-for-responsive-design)

Answer (score 1):

There are several available, responsive table solutions including this simple, CSS-only pattern:

`data-label` **attribute** **:**

First, we’ll add a data-label attribute to each data cell with a value that represents that column’s name. That will be used for labeling purposes in the responsive layout.
In smaller viewports the  and  elements will display as block-level and not as table rows and cells. And the ::before pseudo-class now serves as a label.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }

  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  table td::before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-label="ID">1</td>
            <td data-label="Name">Jake</td>
            <td data-label="Age">23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-label="ID">2</td>
            <td data-label="Name">Dave</td>
            <td data-label="Age">45</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```