# How to split a css flex/grid layout by columns for responsive design

Tags: html, css

I found an old-school html `table` approach which describes my question and a possible solution best:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25010234/2797243

How do I achieve the same on the basis of a more modern CSS?

An example of what is to be achieved:

[image: example]

The current markup looks like this, but it can be easily adjusted:

```
<div>A</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>b</div>
...
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly you're trying to achieve? It would be helpful to show some markup and maybe a diagram of how you want to render it. Also, does it need to be flex, or could it be `display: grid`, eg https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout?

Comment: @maqam7 grid could also be a solution. It's about breaking up tables and transferring the linked table approach to more modern HTML & CSS.

Comment: Cool. As I said, if you could include some markup in your question and also some representation of how you're trying to display that markup then it would be easier to offer a specific CSS solution. The link you provided was a bit too vague to understand the crux of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution using `display: grid`:

```html
<div class="faux-table">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell-header">A</div>
    <div class="cell-content">a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell-header">B</div>
    <div class="cell-content">b</div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

```css
/* Mobile and up */
.faux-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

/* Tablet and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .faux-table {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

/* Desktop and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  .faux-table {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  }
}
```

### See codepen:

https://codepen.io/maqam7/pen/eYWGwpv

### Above code in action:

[image]